Unusual design of a common emitter BJT amplifier
The study and design of the bjt-ce amplifier presented here was conducted by me in the late eighties and improved in the following years. It was aimed at my students in the electronics course and who wanted to experiment with a BJT-CE amplifier with a given voltage gain. The question I ask is:
what is the optimal value of the Thevenin equivalent resistance Rb, given the interval of x=Rc/Re in which Rb has positive values, so that the power dissipated by the entire circuit is minimal with the required voltage gain?
The graphs of the characteristic curves of the BJT are indicative and cannot be used for verification, you must rely on the values ​​provided by the data sheets. The simulation provides a very high voltage gain but lower than required.


(What's unusual in the CE stage shown?)

I guessed IKF will cut beta to 400. And I forgot to add input attenuation of 1/(1+50/(7.912k|1978.772|400*1.3)) or down from 100% to about 89% before it gets into the bipolar. So 260/(26m/((16*1978.772/(7.912k+1978.772)-.7-ln(21m/1m)*.026)/(1592.89404+401*117.069)*401)+.3) * 0.89 gives -145 as the gain. Sorry about forgetting the input attenuation.

@greybeard The calculation procedure seems unusual to me, more precisely the calculation of the equivalent Thevenin resistance RB and the related graph (hyperbola) as a function of the ratio x=Rc/Re. I have never seen it elsewhere.

@periblepsis I think this, as presented by me, is the only rational way to polarize a BJT correctly. I do not accept other approximate methods. My question is: is this design acceptable?

@greybeard I would appreciate it if you could point me to a further source besides the one I mentioned for calculating Rb in the manner described.

@Franc I have no intention of reading that tl;dr presentation. I can though go to the end and use your values to make a quick estimate. I did so. That's all the farther I go. Especially since I don't fathom the actual question. And where i am unsure reading all of it will help. Write better is all I can suggest. That you can accept no other approach but your own just tells me you are unwilling to learn from others. Which is fine. I don't care.

Thanks for the advice.

It’s all just one big image. Text and math shouldn’t be posted as images, people can’t select text and copy.

@GodJihyo Click on the image, a very narrow strip will appear, click on it again and you will see that it will occupy the entire display, then use the print button, at the top right of the keyboard, and select the part of the image that interests you by holding down the left mouse button, then paste it into paint for example or elsewhere.

@Franc And what about screenreaders for accessibility? What if someone who needs this question answered uses a braille interface? And even without those considerations, you've made it needlessly complicated for people to copy segments of your question to indicate what they're responding to. And it's far, far too long besides. This is how you write a question that is unlikely to get answered.

@Franc I wasn't even sure if gain was a goal or not. In this circuit it should not be a goal. In part, some reasons are part variation of beta and IKF and emission coefficient ... and then also temperature, all of which may have significant impacts. In part, the circuit is also highly distorting if the output swing is more than some tens of millivolts. It should never be designed in isolation, but only as part of a larger circuit with global NFB. Given the situation where a specific gain number cannot be the goal, performing a DC bias operating point is usually easy to do.

@Franc One may compute a range of AC gains over temperature and part variation as an exercise to verify that there will be some minimum expected AC gain for the purposes of estimating a minimum total open loop gain in a larger system, though. But a quantitative value for that is also pretty easy to estimate without all that math. And the exact value certainly doesn't matter because the loop will be closed with NFB to set a desired closed loop gain. For that, one just makes sure the open loop gain is not too low. That doesn't require much effort, either.

Let's not forget that with such a voltage gain, thermal noise and other factors are not negligible.

Made with microcap v12

Only changed Rc -> 450 Ohm.
Gain found was ~ -140 (@ 27 °C).  A little more @ -50°C, gain = -160.
